# Rretrieve selected value from Listbox in Python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, unpack

Using python 3.7.2
I want to retrieve the selected entry from a `Listbox`.

I've been playing around with the methods `curselection()`, `selection_set()` and `get()` and rearranged them many times. I've also tried to set `self.libo(selectmode="single")`

```
import tkinter as tk


class Gui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()  # ipadx=3, ipady=3
        self.createWidgets()
        self.createBindings()

    def widget_width(iterable):
        """returns a integer based on the longest entry contained in
        'iterable'. 'iterable' should be a data structure like list, dict or
        tuple."""
        length_counter = 0
        for entry in iterable:
            if len(entry) > length_counter:
                length_counter = len(entry)
        return length_counter

    def createWidgets(self):
        #   Listbox LabelFrame
        self.libo_lafr = tk.LabelFrame(root)
        self.libo_lafr.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        #   Listbox
        self.libo_entries = ("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven")
        self.libo = tk.Listbox(
            self.libo_lafr, width=Gui.widget_width(self.libo_entries),
            height=len(self.libo_entries), selectmode='browse',)
        self.libo.insert("end", *self.libo_entries)
        self.libo.pack()


        self.libo.curselection()
        print(self.libo)
        self.libo_selected = self.libo.selection_set(0)
        print(self.libo_selected)
        self.libo_selection = (self.libo.get(0))
    def createBindings(self):
        self.libo.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", print(self.libo_selection))


root = tk.Tk()
audio_output_switcher = Gui(root)
audio_output_switcher.mainloop()
```

I just want the selected entry from a `Listbox` as a string.

In the version above `self.libo.curselection()` prints `".!labelframe.!listbox"` (without the "), I've seen code examples unpacking `curselection()[0]` and I also read `curselection()` is supposed to return a list but if I try to unpack it I get a `IndexError`.

`self.libo.selection_set(0)` prints `"None"` (without the ")

`self.libo.get(0)` prints "one" (without the "), `self.libo.get(6)` would print `"Seven"`. So `get()` works as expected and lets me access indices `0-6` of the `Listbox` entries.

It's also noteworthy that I only get those print messages after I close the GUI, I've seen some youtube videos where the tkinter GUI would print to the console with the GUI still open, in realtime.

I suspect my error in the `createWidgets()` and `createBidings()` functions, made a double paragraph before the `curselection()` line.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me:

```
def createWidgets(self):
    # Listbox LabelFrame
    self.libo_lafr = tk.LabelFrame(root)
    self.libo_lafr.pack(side="top", padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=2, ipady=2)

    # Listbox
    self.libo_entries = ("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven")
    self.libo = tk.Listbox(
        self.libo_lafr, width=Gui.widget_width(self.libo_entries), height=len(self.libo_entries),
        )
    self.libo.insert(tk.END, *self.libo_entries)
    self.libo.pack()

    self.libo.selection_set(0)
    self.libo_selection = self.libo_entries[int(self.libo.curselection()[0])]

    print(self.libo_selection)
```

`curselection()`returns a tuple of integers, though in some tkinter versions these integers were represented as strings so the need for `int`.  Those integers can be used to index the data you used to create the `Listbox`. You still need to extract first one even if your selection mode doesn't allow for mulitple.

> self.libo.selection_set(0) prints "None"

This code:

```
self.libo_selected = self.libo.selection_set(0)
print(self.libo_selected)
```

should print `None` as `selection_set()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `selection_set(0)` must be returning something cause if i change the index from 0 to 1-6 i get the respective entries from the list printed. my problem is i can't get `curselection()[0]` to return the index of the currently selected entry. if i copy and run your code it still only returns the the first entry of the list instead of the currently selected one.

Comment: `print(int(self.libo.curselection()[0]))` doesn't unpack a selected entry from the list, it just returns what ever index i had put into `self.libo.selection_set()`, so 0 for 0, 1 for 1, 2 for 2 and so on till 6, afterwards it throws a IndexError since the list only has 7 entries.

Comment: @theoka, if I splice my `createWidgets()` function into your program, then change `self.libo.selection_set(0)` to be say `self.libo.selection_set(4)`, the program prints `five` to the console and `five` is selected on menu.  If you can't reproduce those steps then there must be something different with your environment.

Comment: it behaves the same for me. i just noticed if i do `self.libo.selection_set(0, 6)` and run the programm all the entries are selected by default. however, if i click any of the entries with my cursor and close the GUI it does not print the selected value, just the index set for `selection_set()`. or in case of the range 0-6 only the first entry.

Comment: i don't get it, `selection_set(X)` in conjunction with `self.libo_selection = (self.libo.get(int(self.libo.curselection()[0])))` where X stands for a index between 0-6 always just returns that index instead of the one i select with my cursor. if i leave out `selection_set(X)` completely i get a IndexError instead.

Comment: @theoka, I think I understand.  You have a basic misconception.  It wll only print the one we selected in the code.  In order to do more than that you need to define a handler function and install it on the listbox.  Then you can get back selections made after the program starts.